# stuck on installing ruby rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-prompt

im following a tutorial to do this and done step by step untill this came up i seen somone had the same issue but wasnt sorted please someone direct me on how to finish off what im asking it to do many thanks

```
c:\dev\mysql2>gem install mysql2-0.3.13.gem --no-ri --no-rdoc -- --with-mysql-di
r=c:\mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions with: '--with-mysql-dir=c:\mysql-connector-c-noinstal
l-6.0.2-win32'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2-0.3.13.gem:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby200/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb --with-mysql-dir=c:\mysql-connector-c-noi
nstall-6.0.2-win32
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby200/bin/ruby
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:434:in `try_do': The compiler failed to genera
te an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:519:in `try_link0'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:534:in `try_link'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:720:in `try_func'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1004:in `block in have_func'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:895:in `block in checking_for'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:340:in `block (2 levels) in postp
one'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:310:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:340:in `block in postpone'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:310:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:336:in `postpone'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:894:in `checking_for'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1003:in `have_func'
        from extconf.rb:9:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.
3.13 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/ext/mysql2/g
em_make.out

c:\dev\mysql2>
```

Comment: Use Linux :), but seriously, there are loads of answers on this site about installing rails + mysql on windows, have you checked them out?

Comment: Don't try to use Rails on Windows, it never goes well...

Comment: ive gone through em to try n work out what the issue is

Comment: will using linux be as easy as rails tho?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly reccomend using RailsInstaller to create a development stack on windows.

http://railsinstaller.org/en

Comment: Your public ssh key (id_rsa.pub) has been automatically generated and copied t
o your clipboard.      im using windows 8 wth is it on about

Comment: I'm going to need some more information. Consider updating your original question or asking a new one.

Comment: Be sure to run updates on your windows machine and run all commands/exe in administrator mode. Please try to show the log that was created.